# select with ngOptions to select filter of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Edit: Plunker showing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/R5vNvejX3ncdqSzZst17?p=preview

Using AngularJS, I have a primary array that has tasks in it, like:

```
tasks.myTasks = [
    {task: "Task 1", done: "Y"}
    {task: "Task 2", done: "N"}
];
```

I want to set a select on the screen that have three options:

1. Show all tasks.
2. Show only done tasks.
3. Show only undone tasks.

What I've done is set one array with the options, and one variable that is set to the filter when I'm ng-repeating `myTasks`:

```
tasks.filteringOptions = [
    "all": '',
    "only_done": {done: "Y"},
    "only_undone": {done: "N"}
];
tasks.filter = tasks.filteringOptions[0];
```

On my HTML I do my ng-repeat as follows:

```
<select ng-model="tasksCtrl.filter" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in tasksCtrl.filteringOptions">
</select>

<div ng-repeat="task in tasksCtrl.myTasks | filter:tasksCtrl.filter">
   ...
</div>
```

Only problem is that the code above doesn't work, when the first item of the array is selected (`all: ''`) it works fine, but I when I click the select and change it to one of the other options, it doesn't work.

To test it, I commented my `select` out of the HTML code and created an input:

```
<input ng-model="tasksCtrl.filter.done" type="text">
```

This approach worked fine, I type "Y" or "N" into the input and it filters   `myTasks` as expected. So I figured the select was setting wrongly the `tasksCtrl.filter`, so I placed a div with the value of `tasksCtrl.filter` on top of the `select` and `input` and tested them both to see what I would get.

They both returned exactly the same result on my HTML:

```
{"done": "Y"}
```

I have tried to build my `select` with ng-repeat also, but I read online that it doesn't accept objects on it's `value` so I'm using ng-options instead.

I also noticed this: If I try to set the `filter` variable to `{"done": "Y"}`, when I'm using the input it works fine, the first results are already filtered, but if I place the select with the ng-options in it, the filter doesn't work anymore.

The final question is: Do I need to treat my object value to pass it into the ng-options? If not, how can the input and the select show the same result inside the variable `tasksCtrl.filter` and yet the select won't work as expected?

Comment: Throw in a plunker pls

Comment: @Jax here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R5vNvejX3ncdqSzZst17?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Code goes here

var app =angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('custfilter', function(){
  
   
   return function(input, obj)
   {
     var val = JSON.stringify(obj);
     var inputval = JSON.stringify(input);
     //here use jquery to filter and return the data it will work
     return input;   
   }
})



  app.controller('myController1', function(){
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.myTasks = [
      {'task': 'Task 1', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 2', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 3', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'} 
    ];
    
    
    vm.filteringOptions = {
      'all': '',
      'only_done': {done: 'Y'},
      'only_undone': {done: 'N'}
    };
    
    vm.filter = vm.filteringOptions['only_done'];
  
  })
  app.controller('myController2', function(){
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.myTasks = [
      {'task': 'Task 1', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 2', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 3', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'} 
    ];
    
    
    vm.filteringOptions = {
      'all': {done: ''},
      'only_done': {done: 'Y'},
      'only_undone':{done: 'N'},
    };
    
    vm.filter = vm.filteringOptions['only_done'];
  
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>


  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1 as myCtrl1">
      <h1>myController1: input (working)</h1>
      Here I am using a input below to filter myArray.<br/><br/>
      myTasks (filtered):
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in myCtrl1.myTasks | filter:myCtrl1.filter">Task: {{ task.task }} - Done? {{ task.done }} </li>  
      </ul>
      "filter.done" here, type here to see it changing correctly: <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl1.filter">
      
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div ng-controller="myController2 as myCtrl2">
      <h1>myController2: select (not working)</h1>
      Here I have copied and pasted the same controller, identically stablished. But as you can see, it is showing nothing. <br/><br/>
      myTasks (won't show, choose "all" in the select below):
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in myCtrl2.myTasks | custfilter:myCtrl2.filter">Task: {{ task.task }} - Done? {{ task.done }} </li>  
      </ul>
      If you choose "all" it works, otherwise it won't work: <select ng-model="myCtrl2.filter" class="pull-right" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in myCtrl2.filteringOptions"></select>
      
    </div>    
  </body>
```

Comment: I need to filter only the `done` field. I can't filter the whole array with "Y" because there will be "Y's" in the `task` field too. The whole problem is because of this.

Comment: Yes, it worked the way you pointed out... but I can't force the array to filter by `myCtrl2.filter.done`, because there will be other filters in the select. (And if I change the code above to filter by `myCtrl2.filter` it won't work again)

Comment: Can you tick and rank my answers?

Comment: Your answer is not right, the problem I mentioned in my question remains there

Comment: Now try and use jquery filter.. to filter data

Comment: Look, I appreciate your effort, that is one way to solve it. But you are missing the point. I'm trying to understand angular and why the problem is occuring, because ng-options is made with the purpose of using objects as values, and it is not working. I don't want to solve the problem with workarounds. I probably will have to, but the question isn't about that :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

var app =angular.module('pof', []);
 


  app.controller('myController1', function(){
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.myTasks = [
      {'task': 'Task 1', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 2', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 3', 'done': 'Y'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'}, 
      {'task': 'Task 4', 'done': 'N'} 
    ];
    
    
    vm.filteringOptions = {
      'all': '',
      'only_done': {done: 'Y'},
      'only_undone': {done: 'N'}
    };
    
    vm.filter = vm.filteringOptions['only_done'];
  
  })

  app.controller('myController2', function($scope){
      $scope.statuses = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "First Value"        
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Second Value"        
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Third Value"        
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: "Fourth Value"        
    }, {
        id: '',
        name: "All"        
    }];
    $scope.selected_status = 3;
     $scope.data = [
            { id: 1, name: "Max"},
            { id: 2, name: "Adam"},
            { id: 3, name: "Betty" },
            { id: 4, name: "Sara"  },
            { id: 5, name: "Arun"  }
            
        ];
  
  })

  app.directive('bsDropdown', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: '=dropdownData',
            doSelect: '&selectVal',
            selectedItem: '=preselectedItem'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '';
            switch (attrs.menuType) {
                case "button":
                    html += '<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn button-label btn-info">Action</button><button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>';
                    break;
                default:
                    html += '<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="javascript:;">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>';
                    break;
            }
            html += '<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li ng-repeat="item in items"><a tabindex="-1" data-ng-click="selectVal(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li></ul></div>';
            element.append($compile(html)(scope));
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.items.length; i++) {
                if (scope.items[i].id === scope.selectedItem) {
                    scope.bSelectedItem = scope.items[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            scope.selectVal = function (item) {
                switch (attrs.menuType) {
                    case "button":
                        $('button.button-label', element).html(item.name);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $('a.dropdown-toggle', element).html('<b class="caret"></b> ' + item.name);
                        break;
                }
                scope.doSelect({
                    selectedVal: item.id
                });
            };
            scope.selectVal(scope.bSelectedItem);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<link href="http://st.pimg.net/cdn/libs/bootstrap/2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src = "http://st.pimg.net/cdn/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src = "http://st.pimg.net/cdn/libs/bootstrap/2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

   <body ng-app="pof">
  
    <div ng-controller="myController2 as myCtrl2">
      
<bs-dropdown data-menu-type="button" select-val="selected_status = selectedVal"
preselected-item="selected_status" data-dropdown-data="statuses"></bs-dropdown>  &nbsp; Selected Value : {{selected_status}}

<ul ng-repeat="item in data | filter: selected_status">
        <li>{{item.id}} {{item.name}}</li>
 </ul>
    </div>    
   
</body>
```